# Not able to access Leaderboard APi due to HTTP 502 Error

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

The test result shows that the game sign-in function is normal. Therefore, the problem is not caused by a network error. After studying relevant documents, we checked the following items:
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE61w.jpg)
1．  First, we ensured that the package name and app ID belong to the same game.

2．  Then, we checked whether leaderboards have been created for the game in HUAWEI AppGallery Connect. It was found that leaderboards have been added for another game. We attempted to resolve the problem. However, testing shows that the problem still persists.

3．  Finally, it was found that the account we used for testing is not on the list of test accounts in AppGallery Connect. After adding it to the list and clearing HMS Core (APK) cache on the phone, the problem is solved.
I am getting the following error when getRankingIntent API called.

Debug Log-

```
2020-10-22 11:14:17.831 27218-3850/com.huawei.gameassistant W/HwGameAssistant-10.6.0.301-RequestHelper: client.assistant.gs.leaderboard.scores reponse fail code:502, msg:Bad Gateway
2020-10-22 11:14:17.831 27218-3850/com.huawei.gameassistant E/HwGameAssistant-10.6.0.301-GameRankingScoreListViewModel: getHttpStatusCode is : 502
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find that the leaderboard function is abnormal, ensure that:

- The app ID and the package name belong to the same game.
- Your game has its leaderboard data created in AppGallery Connect.
- Your test account has been added in AppGallery Connect.

For more details, check:

[Adding a Leaderboard](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-add_leaderboard?ha_source=hms1)

[Managing Tester Accounts](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-tester_account_mgt?ha_source=hms1)